# Django - Method Not Allowed: (POST)

Tags: django, post, methods

Im new to Django. I am trying to create product archvisation, but when i click on the button to archive i've got error ,,Method Not Allowed (POST)". Dunno how to deal with it.

Here is my code

views.py

```
def to_archive(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = request.POST['to_archive']
        product_archive = Product.objects.get(id=product)
        if not product_archive.is_active:
            product_archive.is_active = True
            product_archive.archived_date = timezone.now
        product_archive.save()
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(_('Archive'), default=False)
    archived_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Archived'), blank=True, null=True)
```

form in html file

```
  <form action="{% url 'to_archive' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="to_archive" value="{{ object }}">
    <input id="disactive_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="To archive">
  </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('to_archive/', to_archive, name='to_archive'),
]
```

Error:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /product/chair/        
Method Not Allowed: /product/chair/        
[09/Sep/2020 13:29:27] "POST /product/chair/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

Comment: Do you have 'return render(your values)'  in your views.py

Comment: I've added ,,return redirect('/')" .  I just want to update filed is_archived from False to True.

Comment: Could you please add the full error that it prints out onto the post, the full one that you see on terminal

Comment: Method Not Allowed (POST): /product/chair/        

Method Not Allowed: /product/chair/        

[09/Sep/2020 13:29:27] "POST /product/chair/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0         

That's all.

Comment: Thanks ill try finding the issue

Comment: I'd be grateful!

Comment: The URL in `Method Not Allowed: /product/chair/` doesn't match either `path('', ...)` or `path('to_archive/', ...)`, so we don't know which view is causing that error.